# assign dataset2 to data set 1 based on ID by conditions-R

Tags: r

I have 2 data sets and I am trying to assign dataset2 to data set 1 based on ID
dataset1:

```
    ID <- c(11,17,23,45,48)
    joined <- c("2020-04-19","2020-04-25","2020-04-22","2020-04-14","2020-04-05")
    transfer <- c("2020-05-19"," ","2020-05-22"," ","2020-05-05")
    promotion <- c("2020-06-09","2020-06-15"," ","2020-06-04","2020-06-25")
    df <- data.frame(ID, joined, transfer, promotion)

dataset2:    
    ID <- c(11,11,11,11,17,17,17,23,23,45,45,48)
    files_submtted  <- c("true","false","true"," ","true","true","false","true"," ","true","false","true")
    task_completed <- c("false","false ","true","true ","true","true","false","true"," ","true","false","true")
    multi_tasking <- c("false","true","false","true","false","true","false","true"," ","true","false","true")
    Date <- c("2020-04-19", "2020-05-19", "2020-06-09","2020-04-25","2020-06-15","2020-04-22", "2020-05-22","2020-04-14","2020-06-04","2020-04-05", "2020-05-05", "2020-06-25")
    df2 <- data.frame(ID, files_submtted, task_completed, multi_tasking, Date)
```

expected output
OUTPUT:

```
    ID files_submtted task_completed multi_tasking       Date    output
    11           true          false         false 2020-04-19    joined  
    11          false         false           true 2020-05-19  transfer
    11           true           true         false 2020-06-09 promotion
    11                         true           true 2020-04-25    
    17           true           true         false 2020-06-15 promotion
    17           true           true          true 2020-04-22    
    17          false          false         false 2020-05-22  
    23           true           true          true 2020-04-14    
    23                                             2020-06-04 
    45           true           true          true 2020-04-05    
    45          false          false         false 2020-05-05  
    48           true           true          true 2020-06-25 promotion
```

Comment: You will need to expand on your logic. For instance, ID 17 ends up with a "transfer" row by the original `df` doesn't have anything there.

Comment: @r2evans I have edited my output could you guide on this

Comment: I'm still confused. ID 17 has a "joined" of 04-25 in `df`, but the output doesn't have a "joined" (likely because there's no `2020-04-25` in `df2`. I suspect this is a merge/join operation, but it's unclear if it's literally on the exact values of `ID` and `Date`, or if there's a "within the range" kind of logic going on.

Comment: @ r2evans I am trying to assign the value based on other dataset

Comment: Okay. I inferred that the match was based on "ID" and "Date", but your expected output is inconsistent with that. Can you verify what your expected logic is?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -ID, values_to = "Date") %>%
  left_join(df2, ., by = c("ID", "Date"))
#    ID files_submtted task_completed multi_tasking       Date      name
# 1  11           true          false         false 2020-04-19    joined
# 2  11          false         false           true 2020-05-19  transfer
# 3  11           true           true         false 2020-06-09 promotion
# 4  11                         true           true 2020-04-25      <NA>
# 5  17           true           true         false 2020-06-15 promotion
# 6  17           true           true          true 2020-04-22      <NA>
# 7  17          false          false         false 2020-05-22      <NA>
# 8  23           true           true          true 2020-04-14      <NA>
# 9  23                                             2020-06-04      <NA>
# 10 45           true           true          true 2020-04-05      <NA>
# 11 45          false          false         false 2020-05-05      <NA>
# 12 48           true           true          true 2020-06-25 promotion
```

Comment: priya, does this answer your question?